# WebBrowser's ScriptErrorsSuppressed not letting me see a page that requires authentication

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser

If you create a C# project (I'm using .NET Framework 4.0), add a `WebBrowser`, set `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` to `true` and navigate to http://vifprogram.com/community/ (which requires the kind of authentication that makes dialog popup for you to enter your credentials), you will get a "This program cannot display the webpage" error.

Any idea why? I tried to replicate this with Internet Explorer by switching the "Disable script debugging" in the internet options, but it works OK whether is checked or unchecked. Is there anything in IE that corresponds to `WebBrowser`'s `ScriptErrorsSuppressed`? If I could at least replicate it in IE I could file a bug or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScriptErrorsSuppressed suppresses not only errors, but also popup boxes such as the authentication box you refer to.

Here is an excerpt from MSDN:
When ScriptErrorsSuppressed is set to true, the WebBrowser control hides all its dialog boxes that originate from the underlying ActiveX control, not just script errors. Occasionally you might need to suppress script errors while displaying dialog boxes such as those used for browser security settings and user login. In this case, set ScriptErrorsSuppressed to false and suppress script errors in a handler for the HtmlWindow.Error event. For more information, see the code example in this topic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed.aspx